# Change font in section headings only

Tags: fonts, sectioning

I'm writing a handbook for an organisation who has specific fonts (Montserrat for Titles and headings; Source Sans Pro for the text).
I can change the font to either of them using
https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/montserratregular/ and
https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/sourcesanspro/, respectively.

But I don't know how to get it into `\allsectionsfont`
Or into `\fontfamily` because the examples I found are for the "standard" fonts.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12p]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
%\usepackage[defaultfam,tabular,lining]{montserrat} %% Option 'defaultfam'
%%% only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{{\fontfamily{Montserrat-TOsF}\selectfont #1}}

\usepackage{sectsty}
    \allsectionsfont{\sffamily}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % never indent first line

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Why join?}

This document is a sample document to 
test font families and font typefaces.\\
{\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont
This text uses a different font typeface
}

\end{document}
```

How do I need to change my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two packages fight each other in how to define `\sfdefault`.

I suggest to first load `sourcesanspro` and make it `\rmdefault`. Then you can load `montserrat`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\usepackage{sourcesanspro}

% set the default font to SourceSansPro
\RenewCommandCopy{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[tabular,lining]{montserrat}

\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % never indent first line

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Why join? \fontname\font}

This document is a sample document to 
test font families and font typefaces.
\fontname\font

\end{document}
```

The `\fontname\font` instructions show what font is being used.

[image]

Without the `default` or `defaultfam` options, the two packages just set `\sfdefault`. After loading `sourcesanspro`, we change `\rmdefault` to what `sourcesanspro` thinks is `\sfdefault`. After that we can load `montserrat` that sets `\sfdefault`.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. Unfortunately, I get
`! Undefined control sequence.
l.9 \RenewCommandCopy
                     {\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}
?`

Comment: How can I fix that?

Comment: @ChrisPeh Use `\renewcommand`. But upgrade your TeX distribution.

Comment: It runs. Unfortunately, I'm getting an output now with both times montserrat...

Comment: Also, I literally downloaded the Tex Live file last week, so not sure how I can make sure I have an upgraded TeX distribution.

Comment: @ChrisPeh Sorry, I should have written `\let\rmdefault\sfdefault`. What OS are you using and what version of TeX Live?

Comment: Awesome - Thank you @egreg. That works!!! I'm using GNU Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon (Edge, Kernel 5.15) and Tex Live is installed from Software Manager with version 2019.20200218-1

Comment: @ChrisPeh On GNU/Linux systems I recommend to install the TUG TeX Live. The one that comes with the distribution is usually years behind the current release and, indeed, you have TL 2019, when the current one is 2022.